# Python install sub-package from package

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, package, installation

it is possible to install some special sub-package from package?

For example, I want to create package with slack, datadog, sentry plugins (wrappers). But I want to allow user what he wants to install.

Like:

```
pip install super_plugins --plugins slack, datadog
```

Can it be done without separating all plugins to different packages?

Comment: You could provide a package with the basics and then provide extensions to download more as needed, similar to `nltk.download()`

Answer (score 9):

Actually, It is quite simple. This is called **Packaging namespace packages**.
https://packaging.python.org/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/

All you need is to separate all packages to sub - packages and after install it with a namespace.

```
# for all packages
pip install super_plugins

# for specific
pip install super_plugins.slack super_plugins.datadog
```

Comment: Is this right? My understanding of namespace packages is that it allows you to have a single package spread across multiple directories, all using the same namespace. Not having optional subpackages within a parent package. Can you give some more details on how you achieved this?