# Is there a way to import a python package from another python package, as if it was part of the same code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-import, python-packaging

Let's say that we have python packages `package_a` and `package_b`. As a user, I want to be able to say:

```py
from package_a.package_b import some_functionality
```

My question is: is there a way to support this without literally copy-pasting the code of `package_b` to `package_a`?

EDIT 1:

To clarify, I have shadow naming (my python package is named the same way as my folder), and I am wondering if there was a way to make the python package available somewhere else.

And yes, I'm looking into ways how to rename the package/folder in a way it still makes sense in the domain.

Comment: Why not just import `package_b`?

Comment: If `package_a` imports `package_b.some_functionality`, you can import `some_functionality` directly from `package_a`.

Comment: Why can't you go into `package_a` and import `some_functionality` from `package_b` there? I'm not quite sure what you're issue is here but can't you just import `some_functionality` into whatever context you need it in?

Comment: @Carcigenicate because of name shadowing. I edited my answer

Comment: @chepner agree, but I have a lot of functionalities to import, which I don't want to import explicitly all the time

Comment: @BrianJoseph I edited my answer to clarify things

Comment: It's not clear what `from package_a.package_b import some_functionality` is supposed to mean. Is `some_functionality` part of `package_a` or `package_b`? Why not just import it directly from the required package? You edit doesn't make clear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an abuse of Python's module system, and I would urge you to reconsider this design, but if you really must, you can do it by messing with `sys.modules`:

In `package_a/__init__.py`:

```
import sys
import package_b

sys.modules[__name__ + '.package_b'] = package_b
```

You can see something like this in the standard lib, `os.path` is either the`ntpath` or `posixpath` module depending on platform, neither of which is actually part of `os` (it couldn't be, `os` is a module, not a package).

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/os.py

```
sys.modules['os.path'] = path
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer (it solves my need), and your warning. I edited my question to clarify how I'm looking into other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

With *setuptools* you can do something like this:

```
Project
├── setup.py
└── src
    ├── package_a
    │   └── __init__.py
    └── package_b
        └── __init__.py
```

`setup.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    name='Project',
    version='0.0.7',
    packages=[
        'package_a',
        'package_b',
        'package_a.package_b',
    ],
    package_dir={
        'package_a': 'src/package_a',
        'package_b': 'src/package_b',
        'package_a.package_b': 'src/package_b',
    },
)
```

This will effectively install two copies of `package_b`, one as a top level package and another one as a sub-package of `package_a`. Which could be a problem since if for example you have a global variables in `package_b` then it won't have the same value as the same global variable in `package_a.package_b`. But it might as well be a positive side effect, depending on the use cases.