# Installing or bundling namespace packages together (PEP 420)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I have several namespace packages. I followed the outline that is sketched in [PEP420](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/) and the [docs](https://packaging.python.org/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/). They are spread out over a few repositories that sometimes bundle them in a deeper namespace.

**Setup**

For example we could have the structure below.

```
Repo1
 /ns_example/src/ns/example/__init__.py
 /ns_example/setup.py

 /ns_another/src/ns/another/__init__.py
 /ns_another/setup.py

Repo2
 /ns_deep/src/ns/deep/one/__init__.py
 /ns_example/setup.py

 /ns_deep/src/ns/deep/two/__init__.py
 /ns_example/setup.py
```

In `setup.py` I create the different packages. Below I specify the two different cases I have from the example above.

```
from setuptools import setup, find_namespace_packages
import datetime

setup(
    name="ns_example",
    version=datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y.%m.%d.%H%M'),
    description='Namespace example',
    packages=find_namespace_packages(where='src', include=['ns.*']),
)
```

```
from setuptools import setup, find_namespace_packages
import datetime

setup(
    name="ns_deep_one",
    version=datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y.%m.%d.%H%M'),
    description='Namespace example',
    packages=find_namespace_packages(where='src', include=['ns.deep.*']),
)
```

**Problem**

This all works, and I can install them with `pip install ns_example` or `pip install ns_deep_one`, but now i want to be able to do `pip install ns` which would install all the packages in the namespace. That however does not seem to work. Why?

Comment: How does the `setup.py` for the `ns` project look like?

Comment: I don't have another setup, so that might explain ^^  Just used the example from the docs. So you need to make a setup for a package that then requires all the individual packages?

Comment: Yes, you could create a `ns` project that doesn't have any code itself but has the other projects as dependencies. I gave an answer to a somewhat related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58167603/11138259